# File management 'Favorites' list customization

Tags: macos, ui, customization, shortcut-menu

Generally I'd do all my file management from the terminal but there are the cases where the GUI is more effective. I'm wondering if it is possible to customize the list of apparent 'Favorites' even though I don't use most of them. I'd like to add my own folders that I have created to that list, is there a way to do this?

[image: GUI file management]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can customize this list of "Favorites" in the Finder. To sort/rearrange the existing items in this list, click and drag them up/down in the list and release the mouse click to change the ordering.

To add an item to this Favorites list, simply click and drag any folder from inside of the Finder content area to this list and it will "stick" to the list in the place where you let go of the click.

To remove an item from the Favorites listing sidebar in the Finder, simply hold down the Shift key on your keyboard and click and drag the item away from the Favorites listing. The dragged icon will turn into a cloud once you drag it so far (releasing the click will remove the sidebar item you've dragged away).

Comment: Thanks dude. oh my I've become horrible at GUIs, i'll come back and give you a +1 if I ever get 15 reputation here

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

To add any directory to your favorites, first, go to your root dir:

Use: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> then type in `/` in the popup.

Navigate to the directory you want and drag it onto `Favorites`.